# WorkbookFactory.create throws ClosedByInterruptException

Tags: apache-poi

I have a multi-threaded java application that spawns as many thread as the reports to be done in a certain moment. At the end of the process, I generate an Excel file with Apache POI (3.15) with `WorkbookFactory.create(file)`, where `file` is an empty template I use to create a brand new Excel file.
With a particular intensive report (it takes hours to be generated), when the code reaches this point, it throws this exception:

```
Caused by: java.nio.channels.ClosedByInterruptException
    at java.nio.channels.spi.AbstractInterruptibleChannel.end(AbstractInterruptibleChannel.java:202)
    at sun.nio.ch.FileChannelImpl.read(FileChannelImpl.java:163)
    at org.apache.poi.util.IOUtils.readFully(IOUtils.java:164)
    at org.apache.poi.poifs.filesystem.NPOIFSFileSystem.<init>(NPOIFSFileSystem.java:229)
    at org.apache.poi.poifs.filesystem.NPOIFSFileSystem.<init>(NPOIFSFileSystem.java:168)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.WorkbookFactory.create(WorkbookFactory.java:250)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.WorkbookFactory.create(WorkbookFactory.java:222)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.WorkbookFactory.create(WorkbookFactory.java:201)
    at it.habble.report.designers.InvoiceCheckDesigner.<init>(InvoiceCheckDesigner.java:87)
```

I've read somewhere it could be related to [limits.conf](https://linux.die.net/man/5/limits.conf) file. Have you any advices on how to investigate on this? Current values:

```
[user@localhost ~]$ ulimit -a
core file size          (blocks, -c) 0
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
scheduling priority             (-e) 0
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
pending signals                 (-i) 191942
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) 64
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited
open files                      (-n) 8192
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 8
POSIX message queues     (bytes, -q) 819200
real-time priority              (-r) 0
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 10240
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes              (-u) 2048
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
file locks                      (-x) unlimited
```

Comment: Excel tag removed

Comment: I would use the InputStream based method - you are calling the NIO version, which is a memory-mapped access to a file, i.e. it will either change the file or if you use the readOnly version, doesn't allow any modifications ... we are currently discussing the buffered mode in [#60741](https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=60741)

Comment: Thanks, but I use the same method for the rest of the reports and I'm not trying to modify it...

Comment: "I'm not trying to modify it ..." ... ok, I think I need to be more explicit. Even if you don't save your template file, a non-private (see discussion in the bugzilla entry) memory-mapped resource will be changed, when you populate your report data. So please use `WorkbookFactory.create(new FileInputStream(file))` instead ...  of course closing the FileInputStream after initialization ... another option would be to copy the template file first to a temp file and call `WorkbookFactory.create(...)` on it